# Quarkus isn't producing JSON from route

Tags: java, json, quarkus

I have a method declared like this:

```
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public List<arbitifer.models.Ticket> all() {
```

The method body just creates a fixed list value and returns it.

The result when I curl this route is:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:8080/tickets
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8080...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /tickets HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-length: 98
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
[Ticket(id=1, story=As a user, I want to see a list of all tickets, so I can see what to work on)]
```

That, um, that is not JSON.

What configuration do I need to add / change to get Quarkus to serialize my model objects into actual / valid JSON?

This is using Quarkus version:

```
<quarkus.platform.version>2.11.3.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that my jackson dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
    <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in `pom.xml` wasn't being processed. Probably forgot to save the `pom.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Using Quarkus project from scratch and testing the endpoint with restassured brings me here. I was getting the exception:

```
groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading 'T', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.
```

Couldn't find why it couldn't parse when it supposed to be JSON. Adding the dependency solved it. Thank you.

Comment: It isn't answer. Looks like new question, or at least comment.